# Ito's differential in portfolio dynamics

Tags: portfolio, itos-lemma

I try to be as concise as possible. Basically I'm following the text "Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time", by Tomas Bjork.

I put here the point where I'm stuck: Chapter 6 - Portfolio Dynamics.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Where does Equation n. 6.7 come from? I mean, the author probably applies the Ito formula to some function, but actually there are no generalized Ito processes in the discussion in order to justify it.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: It's just the Itô [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#Integration_by_parts) [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Product_rule_for_It%C3%B4_processes): $\mathrm{d}(X_tY_t)=X_t\mathrm{d}Y_t+Y_t\mathrm{d}X_t+\mathrm{d}X_t\mathrm{d}Y_t$

Comment: Thank you so much! :)